# Packet Loss Counter

Tags: traffic

While transmitting packets from multiple protocols, is there a way to track packet loss on both the server and the client side in UDP, TCP, Multicast and ICMP?

Comment: `netstat -ni` ?

Comment: no, it doesn't contain Packet loss, although it contains packet drop.